# Running a Java program from the maven test folder which is not a test

Tags: java, maven

I want to put some 'test' programs into the test folder in my maven project.

These programs (with `main()` functions) are not conventional junit tests.  They are just bare apps.

How can I execute them?

- I can't execute them with `mvn exec:java -Dexec=com....test.ClassName` because these test classes do not get bundled into the jar.
- And I can't execute them with `mvn test -Dtest=com....test.ClassName` because they are not junit tests.

Comment: Why don't you just run it without maven?

Comment: @Ozzie I want all the dependencies in the classpath etc.  I've added a proper answer now myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(original poster)

A co-worker worked out that you specify the classpath scope for the exec plugin:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="test" -Dexec.mainClass=com....test.ClassName
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin? Just configure it to be run in the test phase.